# A short story about post nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

Once I heard a unique story from a teacher. I really need to find its title.

Here is the plot: in the post nuclear war times, a man goes to a strange place to find someone who can send people back in time, to live their good moments again. He meets a strange old doctor who claims that he can do such a thing, but he needs all the remaining souvenirs and tokens from the person who asks for this kind of service, and won't give them back afterwards.

The man refuses to give away his souvenirs. He goes back to his family and lives a happy time. Then suddenly he wakes up in the old doctor’s cabinet, realising he gave up and used his souvenirs to relive his memories. The old guy asks if he is satisfied with the service. The man leaves the cabinet to stay alone in his own ruined house in the post-war time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for writing story-identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/202975/edit) additional details into your question.  For example, when did you hear this story?

Comment: Probably the same story as [searching for a story about a man who passes a shop promising to take him to a memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107604/searching-for-a-story-about-a-man-who-passes-a-shop-promising-to-take-him-to-a-m), [I am trying to find a short story about an experience machine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65378/i-am-trying-to-find-a-short-story-about-an-experience-machine) and [Story about post-apocalyptic simulated reality](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184301/story-about-post-apocalyptic-simulated-reality).

Answer (score 14):

["The Store of the Worlds"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58588), by Robert Sheckley. I read it in Brian Aldiss' *More Penguin Science Fiction*, but I believe it's been anthologised several times.

The man's experience consists of a perfectly routine evening at home with his family (presumably killed in the war), and ends with him emerging into a ruined city to hurry off in time for the potato ration. All that totally everyday stuff, now lost, has become precious beyond price.

Comment: This would be greatly improved if you edited to explain why this is correct.